# MongoDB Aggregation of Parent document field in Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, aggregation-framework

```
I am unable to aggregate the field from parent document, 
Example:

Class Animal
{
   int legs;
   int eyes;
   HashMap<String, Object> subSpecies;
}    
Class Tiger extends Animal{
int id;
String name;
String Category;
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
     UnwindOperation unwind = unwind("$subSpecies");
    Aggregation agg = Aggregation.newAggregation(
           Aggregation.match(Criteria.where("category").is("Tigers")),
           unwind,
          Aggregation.group("subSpecies.BengalTiger").count().as("count"),
         project("count","subSpecies.BengalTiger").and("subSpecies.BengalTiger").previousOperation(),
   Aggregation.sort(Sort.Direction.DESC, "count")
  );
  MyServices services = new MyServices();
  //Convert the aggregation result into a List
  List<TigerGroupCount> result =
          services.getAggregationList(agg, Tiger.class, TigerGroupCount.class);
  System.out.println("result:" + result + ",,,,,,,,,," + result.size());
    for (TigerGroupCount tigerGroupCount: result) {
    System.out.println("Status : " + tigerGroupCount.groupName);
    System.out.println("Count : " + tigerGroupCount.count);
  }
    mLogger.info(""+result.size());
}

class TigerGroupCount
{
   int id;
   String groupName;
   long count;
}
```

But here, I am able aggregate with Tiger.name field which is a direct field in Tiger.class. Need to access field - subSpecies which is in parent class(Animal.class).
Any small help is Appreciable.
Thank you in advance.